# Remove "show sharing buttons" metabox Jetpack from custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, plugin-jetpack

I have installed Jetpack and now my custom post types feature a meta-box that says "Sharing: Show sharing buttons" with a checkbox. This is unnecessary for this custom post type and I would like to remove it altogether (not just hide it via screen options).

I tried adding

```
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'my_remove_filters_func' ) );

function my_remove_filters_func() {
    remove_all_filters( 'the_content', 'sharing_display',19 );
    remove_all_filters( 'the_excerpt', 'sharing_display',19 );
}
```

however it doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
if (is_admin()){
  function my_remove_meta_boxes() {
    global $typenow;
    if( 'YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE' == $typenow ) {
      remove_meta_box('sharing_meta', 'YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE', 'high');
    }
  }
  add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );
}
```

Which removes the metabox registered by the jetpack plugin. Just make sure to change `YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE` with the actual name of your custom post type.

Answer (score 2):

As of [Jetpack 3.8.0](https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/3.8.0/modules/sharedaddy/sharedaddy.php#L81), the metaboxes can be remove using a filter:

`add_filter( 'sharing_meta_box_show', '__return_false' );`

So, on a custom post type page, you can use this method:

```php
add_action( 'current_screen', function() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if ( ! empty( $screen->post_type ) && '%POST_TYPE%' === $screen->post_type ) {
        add_filter( 'sharing_meta_box_show', '__return_false' );
    }
});
```

Just replace `%POST_TYPE%` with your custom post type.

Comment: This gets it right.  No fiddling necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the accepted solution didn't work for me because `admin_menu` was firing too early.  Also, `high` is [not a valid argument for `remove_meta_box`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_meta_box/), so I used `advanced` instead.

Here's the updated code:

```
if ( is_admin() ){
    function my_remove_meta_boxes() {
        global $typenow;
        if( 'YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE' == $typenow ) {
            remove_meta_box( 'sharing_meta', 'YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE', 'advanced' );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );
}
```